# Node.js + Socket.io and Redis Store issues when redis restarts

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I'm hoping someone else has encountered this issue before:

#### Issue Description

I have Socket.IO configured to use the redis-store module, which is working great for keeping  our node instances in sync when broadcasting to a room / emitting events.  However I've been testing for failure points and it seems that when the redis instance is restarted the node servers stop receiving messages from other nodes.

Here is how I am setting up the socket.io client (redis connections are created before this bit of code)

```
// Setup the socket server for web clients
self.ioServer = socketIo.listen(9000);
self.ioServer.enable('browser client minification');    // send minified client
self.ioServer.set('log level', 3);

self.ioServer.set( 'store', new socketIo.RedisStore ({
        redisPub: self.redisPub, 
        redisSub: self.redisSub, 
        redisClient: self.redisStore
    })
);
```

In essence, the socket.io redis-store fails to continue sending events through redis to the other node servers whenever redis crashes / restarts.

Are there any special steps that I need to take for reconnecting to the redis server?  I've spent quite a bit of time searching around to hopefully find a solution to this issue, but haven't had any luck.

Regards,

-Ryan

Comment: A note: if you end up using a password on your redis store, you'll need to pass the redis module itself under the 'redis' key as part of your RedisStore constructor. For more info, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438613/redis-auth-error-with-node-js-and-socket-io

Comment: Did you have a chance to fix this? I am curious because I am running Socketio on a cluster of workers and there's a bunch of associated issues. Just ran into them today...

Comment: @mvblfst - Sadly we turned away from Socket.io due to the issues we encountered with this project and switched to Sock.js (https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) and have yet to look back.

I haven't seen the latest changes to Socket.io but I have heard that version 1.0 will include many fixes including the issue with the redis store.  One thing to keep in mind if you consider Sockjs is that is a much lower level library than Socket.io, so if you need channels and groups you will have to build that out your self.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Ryan. I was actually just looking at this https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/wiki/%5BArticle%5D-SockJS:-WebSocket-emulation-done-right under __Load balancing story__. And I do not see their suggestions about shared pool of socket connections - which is the problem we are facing when running socketio on multiple Nodejs threads.

Comment: There are a few directions you can take for that, you can either run multiple 'threads' on the same machine using different ports and let the load balancer handle selecting a server; but I would advise enabling sticky sessions to prevent requests from hitting a different threads that don't have record of that users session.  The other way is: instead of using large machines with multiple threads and servers running on them, use multiple smaller machines each running one process, which helps mitigate the damage of a node failing.  I Hope that helps!

Comment: Also: The reason socket.io has (had?) problems running multiple servers on the same machine, is that if you don't have each server on it's own port + sticky sessions and you are using something like the cluster module to do internal 'load balancing' amongst the processes; there may be a case where a user connects to socket.io using long polling and handshakes fine, but the next call may hit a different 'thread' which won't have any notion of that user and will attempt to re-handshake that user. Sockjs suffers from a similar problem, so the key is to use different ports+sticky sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase anyone is interested here is the fix I've implemented for the above issue:

Since the system is using cluster for the socket.io nodes, I'm catching any 'end' events on the redis connections (reidsPub,redisSub, etc.) and killing the forked process.  On the master  process I catch the exit of the child process and re-fork.

On a side note, I've also discovered another annoying issue with redis and socket.io's redis-store:  The redis connections will eventually timeout if no data is exchanged with redis.  To solve this I've had to implement a simple keep alive function that runs every 15 seconds that exchanges data with redis for all the above redis connections.

Normally I would be ok using the default redis client reconnection logic, but since I have no way of knowing if the redis server actually restarted, or if it was just a timeout.

Comment: can you shed more light on how this resolves the issue whereby data is lost if redis goes down?

Comment: data isn't being written to redis by the socket.io reids-store.  It is publishing / subscribing to specific channels in order to keep a cluster of socket.io servers/processes in sync.

Comment: I'm curious about your solution as it might be helpful to others - I'm assuming that the channels you are referring to are using redis - what happens if all redis instances go down for some reason?  How is data recovered in that case if you do not end up using any structure in redis that is persisted to disk?

Comment: Can you explain how you implemented the "keep alive function that runs every 15 seconds that exchanges data with redis for all the above redis connections." ? I've tried sending "ping", but commands aren't allowed while it's in pub/sub mode.

Comment: @AndrewGee By keep alive I meant that It's sending data between the connections, for pub sub connections simply re-subscribe, or publish data to the correct redis clients.  Emitting data via sockets will probably also do the same thing, however I'm not sure if it will re subscribe to the sub clients.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone over redis-store's implementation in much detail.  I do not believe pub-sub with redis is backed to disk by default and in case the server is restarted, the messages are lost.  Unless redis-store is doing the same already for you, you could use either lists or perhaps sorted sets to store the messages in addition to using pub-sub.

In case not provided by redis-store by default, you will need to ensure that your list/sorted set does not grow too large ti negatively impact performance.  You could look into using MULTI/EXEC (and look into ACK messages) transactions for ACID protection and to ensure that messages are not removed unless processed/consumed by your subscribers.

You could always look into other messaging servers such as ActiveMQ etc which provide durable (disk backed) messaging queues/topics.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Partially, I'm more interested in correctly using the socket.io redis-store, which currently allows me to fork the node process a few times per machine, and still maintain sync across the socket.io processes (for room events, etc).  I'm not sure if the redis-store module in socket.io is properly handling redis restarts.
My Understanding is that the redis-store will allow me to fork the socket.io process multiple times per node machine, as without this module it throws the "warn client not handshaken client should reconnect" error after forking the process and attempting to connect.

Comment: I thought the question was about being unable to send data via redis to other node processes when redis crashes while using pubsub.  WIth redis, pubsub is not backed to disk (you can confirm whether redis-store does that for you - I have not come across any docs which mention that specifically), and if that's the case, you need to implement message reliability on your own - for which I passed a few suggestions (though I am sure one can come up with better options).  good luck

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.  I've dug through the redis-store module for socket.io, and it appears that they weren't planning on handling any redis crashes / restarts, as they only initialize the storage system once.